# No puedo agregar una referencia en Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual, visual-studio-2019, studio

Buen día, estoy tratando de agregar una referencia a en el proyecto, ya que esta hecho por capas. Trato de relacionar la capa Entidad con la capa presentación y me sale el siguiente error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vi en una solución de Visual que decía que para de pasar de Biblioteca de clases a biblioteca de datos, pero esta opción aca no la tengo disponible.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

agrego configuración también de la capa presentación.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano muchas gracias..